# How to apply image change on React element, when hovering over another

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xml, sass

So what I want to do sounds simple. I actually did it before, when I was making this project of mine before learning React, and I used plain JavaScript and JQuery.

So in this Homepage.js component, I have one section and it has 2 children, 's1-left-div' and 's1-right-div'.

Inside the 's1-right-div' resides a 'gradient-img-container' div that basically has an image as a background, set through scss 'background-image: url()' property.
Now, when I hover over any of the 's1-left-div' buttons, I want the image of the 's1-right-div' to change.
Basically, there's 3 buttons on the left div, and I want each one to display its own image in the right div.
And by my experience, I thought it's easy to access and modify the background-image property in scss, but it's just unreachable and I don't know what causes this issue.

Can you help me figure out how to hover and modify properly?
Should be very simple and I feel I'm missing something, but what...
I have shared pastebin links for you in my comment below.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jvDxfwbV   <-- This is my Homepage.js component
https://pastebin.com/U3zc6Jhr    <-- This is my corresponding scss file

Answer (score 0):

The way I would structure this would be to create a state variable in the parent node and four functions:

```
  const [backgroundImage, setBackgroundImage] = useState(defaultImageUrl);
  function hover1() {
     setBackgroundImage(image1Url);
  }
  function hover2() {
     setBackgroundImage(image2Url);
  }
  function hover3() {
     setBackgroundImage(image3Url);
  }
  function exitHover() {
     setBackgroundImage(defaultImageUrl);
  }
```

Then pass as props to the child component with the buttons.

```
    <button 
        onMouseOver=props.hover1 
        onMouseExit=props.exitHover
     >
     </button>
```

Repeat for the other buttons as well.

For the child div component that you want the background to change, pass the backgroundImage state variable.

```
    <div 
        style={{"background-image":props.backgroundImage}}
    >
    </div>
```

Now every time you hover on one of the buttons the backgroundImage state variable will be changed from the hover functions in the parent node to display the background you want.

Comment: thank you my friend. Though I didn't use 'props' because we're inside the same component.
I imported the images in order to include them instead of url links, cause I had trouble with that, and it works perfectly. Thanks for your contribution to this solution!

Comment: Pleasure. Good luck with the project!